# Is it possible to use two communication protocols in one microcontroller?

Tags: atmega, serial, i2c, beaglebone-black

So I've been trying to communicate between the Beaglebone Black and atmega through I2C for quite such time and have been facing quite a lot of problems with it.

On the other hand I can successfully communicate between two Atmega through I2C with ease.

So here's the problem, My project deadlines coming up and I'm sorta desperate and I was thinking if it's possible that I get data through I2C on an Atmega and then from the same Atmega serially transmit all the data on the beaglebone black for later processing. Is this realistically speaking possible or will I be facing some problem that I'm not aware about?

Comment: Yes​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Sure. You're probably having trouble on the I2C front since both chips demand being the master. While I2C is multi-master in theory, many chips are having trouble with this part of the spec and sometimes even rule it out explicitly. I'm blaming the Beaglebone here.

Comment: But I am using the atmega as a slave and the beaglebone as a master. so the multi master case shouldn't apply. Why does the problem still occur?

Answer (score 1):

The only problem you may face is resources on your ATMega, but in general, serial uart communication on one set of pins (bit-banged or dedicated peripheral) and i2c on another set of pins (again, bit-banged or dedicated), is quite simple and often done.

The other option is directly connecting your i2c slaves to the BBB and reading them from there, ditching the ATMega, if you can.

Based on your comments, there is some bug between the BBB (Master) and ATmega (Slave) communication. Serial would allow you to bypass that i2c bug, but you could always end up having a bug on the serial code. You just want to keep that in mind. The quickest way to find the bug would be a logic analyzer with i2c support.

Comment: I was using all the atmegas and slaves and the beaglebone as the master previously but for some reason the code which I had written worked perfectly between two Atmega (this was just a test to see if my code was working) but didn't work when I used it with the beaglebone black.

Comment: @RohanNarlanka at what i2c speed? Are you dealing with clock stretching at all? What drivers are you using on the BBB?

Comment: i2c is working at the standard 100kbps speed. No clock stretching yet. And on the BBB I'm using the standard i2c-tools library to detect and read the i2c values.

Comment: How exactly is it failing? @RohanNarlanka

Comment: the BBB doesn't detect the address of the atmega. It did once and I could transmit the data without any problem but since then it hasn't detected it again. I've tried it with different atmega and different beaglebones thinking that maybe there was a problem with the hardware. But there has been no change in the code and the hardware works perfectly fine. I am clueless to why they are behaving like this.

Comment: @RohanNarlanka what voltage was your ATMega running at?

Comment: @RohanNarlanka your using the right i2c bus? the BBB has 3, only two which are active, and I'm assuming your ATmega is acting as an eeprom/eeprom address? Is your ATmega 3.3V or 5V? Pull-up resistors to what voltage?

Comment: the BBB has inbuilt pull-ups and works at a logic of 3.3v. I step down my atmega's logic from 5 to 3.3 by using a bi-directional logic level converter. I'm quite confident I'm using the right bus. It's generally the 2nd (of 0,1 and 2) but I always check all the 3 buses. @Passerby